# Overlap Circuitikz and Pgfplots figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, circuitikz

My problem today is to get to fit an electrical circuit (drawned using mainly \draw) into a Tikz Axis.

I am using the Axis command to plot (using \addplot) a curve from a set of points (no problems so far), but I can't figure out how Tikzpicture works about anchors and all that, to make things not go berserk, but stay in place.

To get clearer, here is the code where I make 3 axis (so 3 subfigures if you prefer, 2 on top and one on bottom left) :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
% Vs(ve) graphique

  \begin{axis}[name=plot1
    ]
    \addplot[black] table {Fig_ELA2/ELA2_P3_C3/ELA2_P3_C1_PP_CLASSE_B/courbes/vs_ve_out.txt};
  \end{axis}
  
% Vs(wt) graphique
  \begin{axis}[name=plot2,at={($(plot1.east)+(1.5cm,0)$)},anchor=west
    ]
    \addplot[black] table {Fig_ELA2/ELA2_P3_C3/ELA2_P3_C1_PP_CLASSE_B/courbes/vs_t_out.txt};
  \end{axis}
  
% Ve(wt) graphique
  \begin{axis}[name=plot3,at={($(plot1.south)-(0,1.5cm)$)},anchor=north
    ]
    \addplot[black] table {Fig_ELA2/ELA2_P3_C3/ELA2_P3_C1_PP_CLASSE_B/courbes/ve_t_out.txt};
  \end{axis}

% Electrical circuit
  \draw
    (0,0) node[njfet](J){$J$}
    (J.S) to[short,-o] ++(0,-0.1) node[left](S){\tiny S} to [R, l_=$R_S$,-*] (0,-3) node(gnd_rs)[ground]{}
    (J.D) to[short,-o] ++(0,0.3) node[left](D){\tiny D} to [R, l=$R_D$] ++(0,2) node[vcc]{\color{green} $V_{CC}$}
    (J.G) to[short,-o] ++(-0.1,0) node[above](G){\tiny G}-- ++(-1,0) node(RG){}
    ;
    \coordinate (gnd_rg) at (RG|-gnd_rs);
    \draw (RG) to [R, l_=$R_G$,-*] (gnd_rg);
    \draw (gnd_rs) to[short,-o] ++(-4,0) node(gnd_ve){};
    \draw (gnd_rs) to[short,-*] ++(1,0) node(gnd_cs){} to[short,-o] ++(2,0) node(gnd_vs){};
    \coordinate (ve) at (gnd_ve|-J.G);
    \draw (ve) to[C,l=$C_{Le}$,o-*] (RG);
    \coordinate (vs) at (gnd_vs|-D);
    \draw (D) to[C,l=$C_{Ls}$,-o] (vs);
    \coordinate (cs) at (S-|gnd_cs);
    \draw (S) -- (cs) to[C,l=$C_S$,] (gnd_cs);
    \draw[-triangle 45, red] (gnd_vs) -- (vs) node[right,pos=0.5]{$v_s(t)$};
    \draw[-triangle 45, red] (gnd_ve) -- (ve) node[left,pos=0.5]{$v_e(t)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm sorry about not giving the curves for you to test, you can just make dumb ones I guess (or no addplot at all).

So is there a way to set somehow the electrical circuit as absolute, and make it behave like absolute in CSS (so out of the flow).

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Each axis environment is placed with (0,0) on the lower left corner.  You can use `\begin{scope}[shift={(x,y)}] ... \end{scope}` to apply an arbitrary shift.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Could you please add to your example a minimal preamble to make it compilable out-of-the-box? It would be much easier for us to help!

Comment: ...and you should add the data you are plotting or use a dummy data. Like it is now, it is impossible to run your example without your files...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You should always try to post self-contained examples so that people wanting to help can do it without guessing your preamble or definitions. Nevertheless, this is an option --- notice that:

1. in your circuit, you have just one absolute coordinate, the `(0,-3)` in the first line, which I fixed (and made your circuit unable to be translated).
2. even then, the circuit is quite big, so I scaled it with a `scope` environment.

So you can do a thing like this (adjusting the `++(6,-5)` by hand; it's possible to do a more automatic thing, but that's another story, and it will be told another day...)

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    % Vs(ve) graphique

    \begin{axis}[name=plot1
        ]
        \addplot[black] {sin(x)};
    \end{axis}

    % Vs(wt) graphique
    \begin{axis}[name=plot2,at={($(plot1.east)+(1.5cm,0)$)},anchor=west
        ]
        \addplot[black] {cos(x)};
    \end{axis}

    % Ve(wt) graphique
    \begin{axis}[name=plot3,at={($(plot1.south)-(0,1.5cm)$)},anchor=north
        ]
        \addplot[black] {x};
    \end{axis}

    % Electrical circuit
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.8, transform shape]
        \draw
            (plot1.south east) ++(6,-5) node[njfet](J){$J$}
            (J.S) to[short,-o] ++(0,-0.1) node[left](S){\tiny S} to [R, l_=$R_S$,-*] ++(0,-3) node(gnd_rs)[ground]{}
            (J.D) to[short,-o] ++(0,0.3) node[left](D){\tiny D} to [R, l=$R_D$] ++(0,2) node[vcc]{\color{green} $V_{CC}$}
            (J.G) to[short,-o] ++(-0.1,0) node[above](G){\tiny G}-- ++(-1,0) node(RG){}
            ;
        \coordinate (gnd_rg) at (RG|-gnd_rs);
        \draw (RG) to [R, l_=$R_G$,-*] (gnd_rg);
        \draw (gnd_rs) to[short,-o] ++(-4,0) node(gnd_ve){};
        \draw (gnd_rs) to[short,-*] ++(1,0) node(gnd_cs){} to[short,-o] ++(2,0) node(gnd_vs){};
        \coordinate (ve) at (gnd_ve|-J.G);
        \draw (ve) to[C,l=$C_{Le}$,o-*] (RG);
        \coordinate (vs) at (gnd_vs|-D);
        \draw (D) to[C,l=$C_{Ls}$,-o] (vs);
        \coordinate (cs) at (S-|gnd_cs);
        \draw (S) -- (cs) to[C,l=$C_S$,] (gnd_cs);
        \draw[->, red] (gnd_vs) -- (vs) node[right,pos=0.5]{$v_s(t)$};
        \draw[->, red] (gnd_ve) -- (ve) node[left,pos=0.5]{$v_e(t)$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: picture from the code above]